# can I configure build to happen every minute but deploy should happen only once a day in a single Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In a single Jenkins job, we can trigger a build by specifying a `schedule` and also by `polling`. But then, in both the cases, the build is triggered, and the deploy operation that I have configured as a post-build step (using `PostBuild Task` plugin) also happens. I want that the build happens whenever a change is detected by polling, but deploy should happen only according to the schedule I have provided.

Is it possible to do it in a single job, or do I have to configure 2 separate jobs for them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you are using `PostBuild Task` plugin. This allows to do a regular expression on the console log to determine whether to execute a task or not.

Builds started by schedule will have `Started by timer` at the top of the log. All you need to do is add this expression to your PostBuild step under "Log Text" field. If you are already using some criteria in there, click "Add" button to add another "Log Text" field, and use the "AND" operator between them

Answer (score 1):

It will be cleaner to do it in 2 jobs. However, if you really need to have it in one job, you could use a combination of Jenkins plugins to do the job.

- Use EnvInject Plugin to expose the BUILD_CAUSE and/or BUILD_CAUSE_SCHEDULED* environment variable(s). (This may not be necessary, you might be able to reference the Jenkins variables within the Jenkins configuration by default)
- Use Flexible Publish plugin, post-build action, to set up a conditional publish step when BUILD_CAUSE == SCHEDULED, or when BUILD_CAUSE_SCHEDULED == true. (Just test one condition.) Note that you'll need to use Jenkins' expression syntax, like so:

  ```
  ${ENV,var="BUILD_CAUSE_SCHEDULED"}
  ```

* BUILD_CAUSE_SCHEDULED is not its real name, you'll need to find this out on your own, sorry.